# Adding Power losses to the GA constraints By Matlab?

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I am coding GA in Matlab to do economic dispatch in ten generating units and I want to implement the condition of ( P generation = Pload +P losses ) and I create a Function to calculate P losses using B matrix, But I cant add it to GA Constraints.

Comment: Please provide some more context and a code snippet of what you have tried, and explain what you mean by `But I cant add it to GA Constraints`.

Comment: the GA syntax and here i can not add the loooses specially it is function of the GA output
A =[];
b =[];
Aeq = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
beq =1036+line_Losses;
lb = [150 135 73 60 73 57 20 47 20 10];
ub =[470 470 340 300 243 160 130 120 80 55];
p = ga(@thermal_cost,10,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
    the function to calaclate losses using B matrix
p =[p(1) p(2) p(3) p(4) p(5) p(6) p(7) p(8) p(9) p(10)];
j=10;
i=10;
Losses=0.000;  
  for (i = 1:10)
  for (j = 1:10)
   Losses= Losses +  p(i).*B(i,j).*p(j) ;
  end
  end
Losses

Comment: this is the code and as i told you i can not add the looses constraints to GA matlab

Comment: @Yes but you should add it to the question rather than as a comment.

Comment: ok i will do that but can you help me in this issue